# python long integer division error. how do I fix this?

Tags: python, math, runtime-error

This problem arose from my prime factorization function.
When I try to divide a long integer with integer. It gives a value in 
scientific notation. And it is not exactly correct answer.

```
18291821821212182811 / 3 = 6.097273940404061e+18
```

here,

`6.097273940404061e+18` is the same as  this, `6097273940404061000`

`6097273940404061000 * 3` must be equal to `18291821821212182811`

but there is 189 integer differences.

`6097273940404061000 * 3` is 189 bigger than `18291821821212182811`

`6097273940404061000 * 3 - 18291821821212182811` = `189`

So why does this not give exact number?? 
I am thinking that the python changes the form into scientific notation with floating point and that leads to arithmetic error.
Is there any way around this ? Is there any way I can tell python not to
change it into floating point during the calculation if that's the problem.

Comment: You can use `//` to get floor (integer) division. Floating point values are *approximations* (for performance reasons).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use integer division `//`:

```
18291821821212182811 // 3 = 6097273940404060937
```